# Email Template Not Rendering Correctly in Gmail Mobile App on IPhone 11 & 12

Tags: html, css, templates, gmail, html-email

I'm designing a new email template, but I'm not a developer. I mostly use HTML, some CSS. My templates aren't rendering correctly in the Apple mobile version in Gmail. They are skewed to the left and do not display their full width.
I've tried adding in responsive codes for both mobile and desktop and setting max widths and heights, but I seem to only have this issue with Gmail Mobile & IPhone 11 & 12, it looks great on all other email clients. Does anyone have any code suggestions?

Comment: We'd need to see your code thus far

Answer (score 1):

From my research on similar challenges, I found that there is an option of "Auto-resize" or "Auto-fit" that often gives problems

The solution was to add a min-width: (the size of my widest bit of the email).

Besides you would be required to compose your view through nested tables, since often the html used in these email clients are pretty old and not updated, you can look in for which all features are supported using this: https://www.caniemail.com/

For more information on your problem you can look into this

https://litmus.com/community/discussions/257-gmail-app-android-how-to-stop-text-from-auto-resizing

Answer (score 0):

use nested tables instead of divs and try to keep your template sample as possible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31334785)